# Connecting to MySQL using zend

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, connection, firewall, port

I've set up a virtual host on my local machine myhost.com, have installed zend there and am now trying to connect to the MySQLdatabase. I get the following error message:

> Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on ''myhost.com'' (10060)

All the tips I've found via google haven't helped. I use kaspersky antivirus and have added port 3306 to the allowed list for MySQL and Apache. I've also pinged myhost.com:3306 and get a response (with ip address 67.63.50.51), though localhost:3306 and 127.0.0.1:3306 aren't found. I've checked that other apps can still access MySQL if the virtual host is pointed at them instead and my non zend apps do work.

I guess I have to do something further to the port, or maybe force the app to use a different port, but am not sure how to do either.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What OS? If you goto a command prompt and type "mysql" does it launch into SQL? I don't necessarily think its a port problem.

Comment: It's windows XP with a standard xampp installation and more or less the latest zend release. And typing in mysql leads to a not found error, which is strange. Like I said, MySql is connected OK by other apps.

Comment: Aight one more question :)

You said you setup a virtual host on the machine for "myhost.com", is this a real domain in which the DNS is pointed to the machine? Like, when you ping "myhost.com" from that machine, does it resolve to the local machine or someplace else? Are their hacked hosts files involved? I wasn't sure if you used "myhost.com" as an example or as a real domain.

Comment: That's definintely not the problem. I just double-checked again by pointing localhost to where the virtualhost was pointing, and it fails on localhost too, though with a slightly different error:

Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host ''localhost'' (11001)

Comment: 2 Ideas: 
#1 Post up some code in the original question with the connection string, what config info your using to connect (blank out the pass) and the code your using. #2, if your sure its not the code, we should flag this and move it to ServerFault.

Comment: I just copied across to server fault as I thought it might be a better place. Will delete this question later if it turns out to be a server issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a simple one in the end.

The tutorial I'm working through had quotation marks around its db connection details, and it turns out I needed to leave these out.

Answer (score 1):

10060 is just the error number.  MySQL's default port is 3306.  Try the same things you already tried, but using that correct port.

Comment: Much as I hoped this would clear up the problem, I've retried everything with 3306 and the problem still persists